# How to control the colors of a download link on an HTML page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a download button with HTML, CSS and (hopefully) Bootstrap.

The button works, but the text with the anchor tag is very faded.

In my header I have this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and in the Styles section I have this:

```
.btnx {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
 
.btnx {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  ont-size: 20px;
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.btnx:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
```

(I used btnx so as not to screw up other buttons until I have this down correctly)

The code is quite simple:

```
<button class="btnx"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download the file</button>
<button type="button" class="btnx"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> 
<a href="/pathtodownloadfile">Download the File</a></button>
<p>
<a href="images/Portfolio.pdf" class="btnx" download><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download CV</a>
</p>
```

The problem is: the first one, without the anchor, the text is not bad but the white could be brighter (bolder)
But the second one, with the anchor tag, the text is a blue.
The third one works but the unselected element's background is faded.

Is there a way to use the anchor tag and keep the text bright white?

[image]

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: https://validator.nu/

Comment: What do you mean by "the text is not bad but the white could be brighter (bolder)"? The text is as white as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code when you want to download a file

```
<button class="btnx"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download the file</button>
<button type="button" class="btnx" onclick="download('/pathtodownloadfile')">
   <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download the File
</button>
<p>
   <a href="images/Portfolio.pdf" class="btnx" download>
      <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download CV
   </a>
</p>

<script>
    function download(uri) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.download = uri.split("/").pop(); // this gets last segment of uri
        link.href = encodeURI(uri);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the colour of a *link* then change the colour of the **link** … and not just one of its ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need `a` tag in your button. You can use `onclick` event.

```
<button class="btnx"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download the file</button>
<button type="button" class="btnx" onclick='window.location.href = "/pathtodownloadfile"'>
   <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download the File
</button>
<p>
   <a href="images/Portfolio.pdf" class="btnx" download>
      <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download CV
   </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: One question: this works well with executables. But when the file ends in txt, it is not downloaded but displayed as text in the browser. Is there a way to force it to download?

Comment: This works: <button type="button" class="btnx" onclick='window.location.href = "mytext.txt"'><i class="fa fa-download"></i> 
My Text</button>   but again the text is very pale.

Comment: if you want to download any file includes txt too, then I answer this question again with a javascript function. You can use that.

Comment: I added the javascript function. Did not work. What gets downloaded is a file with the correct name but the contents are the path specified to the Javascript function, not the actual file itself.

Comment: I added the javascript function. Did not work. What gets downloaded is a file with the correct name but the contents are the path specified to the Javascript function, not the actual file itself.

<button type="button" class="btnx" onclick="download('/pathtothefile/filename.txt')">
   <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download the File
</button>

Comment: And this downloads the file's data but to a tab in Chrome:

<button type="button" class="btnx" onclick='window.location.href = "/pathtofile"'>
   <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download the File
</button><br/><br/>

Answer (score 0):

As much as I am able to understand your question, I have made some changes to your code which you may check in the snippet below:

```css
.btnx {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
 
.btnx {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.btnx:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}

button a, button a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></head>
<button class="btnx"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download the file</button>
<button type="button" class="btnx"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> 
<a href="/pathtodownloadfile">Download the File</a></button>
<p>
<a href="images/Portfolio.pdf" class="btnx" download><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download CV</a>
</p>
```